# Is making an Open Graph 2.0+ call destructive in any way to an Open Graph 1.0 app?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

We have an **app that exclusively uses Open Graph 1.0**, and we are aware that this API is deprecated. Our app was created before April 30th, 2014.

However, we **would like to implement Open Graph 2.0** (or higher) features in production *before* we migrate away from 1.0.

**Will this in any way affect our ability to use the Open Graph 1.0 API?**

I spent some time looking through the Facebook documentation, but couldn't find the answer to this specific question. Any experience or links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, with some caveats / things to watch for

Any individual calls can be made against any API version which was in effect when your app was first created and hasn't yet been removed - for an app created today, that's version 2.1, for an app created before April 2014, that's `v1.0`, `v2.0` and `v2.1`

If you try to make a call and specify a version that's no longer available, the call will implicitly be made against the oldest currently-supported version - this is the same as if you don't specify a version, so your existing code in an older app will be calling `v1.0` implicitly now, even though you don't have it specified in the API call path

One caveat to this is that newer SDKs (e.g. PHP, iOS, Android) will default to calling the newest API version available at the time that SDK was released and to call older versions from those SDKs you'll need you override the default or the version used for each/some calls - how this is done varies by SDK, the docs should clarify though

Also, a user using a version of the Oauth / Login Dialog from a recent version (e.g. v2.1) won't be able to grant permissions that were removed in earlier versions using that version of the dialog, they'd need to use the old dialog to grant older permissions 
For example, /v2.1/dialogs/oauth won't prompt users to grant any of the `friends_*` permissions removed in v2.0, `user_friends` added in v2.0 to allow access to the list of a user's friends who also use the app, etc

So if your users are granting permissions using newer versions of SDKs, you need to be careful that other versions of your client code aren't assuming a logged in Facebook user will have granted those permissions as the calls will not work as expected